# How to update JQuery in PrestaShop 1.6?

Tags: jquery, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, fancybox-3

I'm using **Prestashop 1.6**. I think I need to update the JQuery version to use **Fancybox 3**.

I looked at FTP */public_html/js/jquery*, ***jquery-1.11.0.min.js*** file is available. So JQuery is not up to date. I changed the name of this file to ***old_jquery-1.11.0.min.js***. I have installed the **jquery-3.4.1.min.js** file. But it doesn't work.

Is there a configuration file in which I can enter the current file path? Or is the update done in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PrestaShop is using the `addJquery()` method from the `Controller` class which allows you to decides which path/version of Jquery you'd like to include for a specific page. This also allows you to run two versions of jQuery at the same time (by using the `noConflict` flag [as described here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+jQuery+and+jQueryUI))

The `addJquery()` method uses a static method to get jQuery's path: `Media::getJqueryPath()` which is itself using the `_PS_JQUERY_VERSION_` constant.

Therefore, there are two places where you would need to make changes:

**Admin Panel**

- File: `classes/controller/AdminController.php` on line `3831` in PrestaShop 1.6.1.24

  `<script src='"._PS_JS_DIR_."jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>`

**Defines**

- File: `/config/defines.inc.php` on line `217` in PrestaShop 1.6.1.24

  `define('_PS_JQUERY_VERSION_', '1.11.0');`

However, I would recommend against it due to possible side effects with some jQuery plugins used by PrestaShop (both on the back-end and front-end).

A alternate solution would be to:

- Keep these files as is
- Override the `setMedia()` method in `classes/controller/FrontController.php`
- Specify the jQuery 3.4.1 version in  `$this->addJquery()` (line 952 in PrestaShop 1.6.1.24) - only if you detect that the current controller is ProductControllerCore

I hope this helps!